# How to run an existing node app from github?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I'm very new to JavaScript application development, had few tutorials here and there, but nothing much to write home about. :)

- I am trying to run this app/website on my PC:
  https://github.com/albinotonnina/albinotonnina.com
- Downloaded/cloned source code from github
- Node is installed on my windows 10 PC

I've no idea how to start this app. Can anyone please help me with starting this on localserver?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

You have first to clone your repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/albinotonnina/albinotonnina.com your-destination-folder
```

then when the repository has been cloned:

```
cd your-destination-folder
npm install # installing the dependencies
npm start # or 'node .'
```

**Clone documentation**
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone
**Npm start documentation**
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html

> I've seen that maybe the build process is requested for that project:
>   as they say in the Readme.MD you have to build the app like this:
>
> ```
> npm run build
> ```
>
> Or
>
> ```
> npm run dev
> ```
>
> for running in dev the project. Inside the package.json you can see
>   what this commands do under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is "cloning" a git repo on your local
So, you might wanna look here -

https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html

Also, I strongly recommend going through some Git basics, probably here

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: I already have source code cloned/downloaded on my local machine. Facing problem running it :)

Comment: have you tried just navigating to the directory you downloaded it in a terminal window and running `npm start`

Comment: Thank you @TommyBs, it was npm build and then npm start. and bingo!!! :)  if you could write this as an answer? My first step towards nodejs!! :)